# Access to base class method only from the derived class

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

For example, I have two classes:

```
class Foo
{
  protected void say() {...};
}

class Bar extends Foo {.....}
```

Can I somehow allow the "say" method to be called only from the Bar and other derived classes, but not from the other classes in Foo's package.

Comment: Making Foo `abstract` may be a solution if that fits your architecture.

Comment: @Merguez I don't see how that might be a solution...

Comment: @m0skit0 I think i misinterpreted a bit. But that would make the `say()` method inaccessible by classes not extending Foo (because you can't generate an instance of Foo)

Comment: @Merguez You're correct indeed, that would be a valid solution if no Foo instances are required.

Comment: Sadly, Foo instances can be required to provide the default implementation.
Also, if the Bar is in the same package as Foo, it's "say" method can be accessed by the other classes too. So the abstract isn't 100% right decision. However, it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, protected mean, protected member can be accessed in the same package and all subclasses in any package. If you want to restrict the access in package level, move that class into a separate package.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I was thinking about passing an object as a parametre and using instanceof in the "say", but it's too dirty and not obvious for others. So, you either move your class in the new package or cooperate with the people, who are working with the current package. Amirite?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way how you can do this in java.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such accessor in Java that meet your needs, and AFAIK it's not possible to implement that restriction (in a simple way, that is, and besides [Kugathasan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609217/898478)).